# How to set datemodified property for a Storage file in c# uwp?

Tags: uwp, storagefile

I need to set specific time for date modified property, not current time.

I can't use FileInfo because the file is located in folder outside \AppData\Local\Packages<packagename>\LocalState  (system.io has no access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set datemodified property for a Storage file in c# uwp?

UWP has [`SavePropertiesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.savepropertiesasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-storage-fileproperties-basicproperties-savepropertiesasync(windows-foundation-collections-iiterable((windows-foundation-collections-ikeyvaluepair((system-string-system-object)))))) method that could use to modify basic property, unfortunately, [`System.DateModified`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-datemodified) is Innate, so we can't update it manually in uwp platform as this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/215744/while-saving-photo-file-properties-it-throws-argum.html) said. For this scenario, we suggest update `FileInfo` use desktop extension, for more you could refer to  stefan's blog **UWP with Desktop Extension**. And the other way is copy the file into app's local folder, and put it back after modified property

The following is sample code that update  LastWriteTime within desktop extension

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
    fi.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nico. If I use desktop extensions will I have difficulty getting into app store?

Comment: Yes, because you have used runFullTrust  capability,  You may request approval for these capabilities in apps that you submit to the Store. and here is [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/preparing-a-desktop-bridge-application-for-the-store-submission/ba-p/316909)that you could refer to.